# Mysql data returning from php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to return some data from my database, with a query which is in a var. So he gets the query but does not seem to collect the data from the database, he also makes the connection to the database cause i have my connection in a seperate file which I include in my .php file.

Below is my code to get that data:

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM verkoper";
                var_dump($sql);
                $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                var_dump($result); die();
            ?> 
            <select name="verkoper">
                <?php
                # voer de SQL statement SELECT uit
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['naamverkoper'] . "'>" . $row['naamverkoper'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
```

The first part is where i dump my query which gives the whole select statement. But the line under that does not seem to do anything.

Little help or tips on what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks!

Comment: the die() after  var_dump($result)?  terminate the process

Comment: never use empty die(), use die("SOME_MESSAGE_HERE") or `die( __FILE__ .':'.__LINE__)`, so you can find where it happened. Because in some cases PHP can die from memory errors or segfault and you will not have any clue what happened, until you search through logs (using php-fpm, for example). Sometimes you forget you used die() - like in this case.

Comment: $mysqli->query() : For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN queries it will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries it will return TRUE. FALSE on failure.

Comment: @scaisEdge ofcourse it terminates the proces but it should still give me the data stored in my db ..

Comment: But in this way is not execute the echo ... then removing you should see the echo of the while loop ..

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code and get the ***real*** reason why your code is failing ;-) we also don't know which API you're using to connect with neither and if that is indeed your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
die();
```

and check the result.

Comment: Even if i remove the die(); I have no result from the database.

Comment: Make sure $result variable is properly populated. You can `echo(mysqli_num_rows($result));` also

Answer (score 0):

Remove $ from mysqli function, and just try with procedural style,

mysqli->query($sql)